# Rename Files in Salesforce after processing - using Mule

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, salesforce-lightning, mule4, mule-connector

Is there a way to rename a file attached to a Salesforce Object using Mule ?
( In my case, a file is uploaded to an Opportunity Object. I need to download the VersionData, process the file and update the fields in Salesforce. And then rename the file in Salesforce).

After I process the file, Should I use the Salesforce Update Connector and update the 'Title' or 'PathOnClient' of the specific Object or Is there any other way we could do this?

Comment: Do you know if this is possible using pure Salesforce APIs without using Mule?

Comment: Hi @aled, I'm not sure I follow your question. But if you mean, is it possible from the Salesforce end, Yes it is!